# What's the difference between $@ and $*?

Tags: bash, shell

What's the difference between `$@` and `$*`? Why they have the same value but `"$@"` and `"$*"` are different when I set `IFS` to `|`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between `$@` and `$*`: Unquoted (don't do this!), none at all: both equal `$1 $2` .... With double quotes, `$@` expands each element as an argument: `$1` `$2` ..., while `$*` expands to all elements merged into one argument: `$1c$2c...` (where c is the first character of IFS). You almost always want `$@`. The same goes for arrays: `${myarray[@]}`